# SimpleCov: Not run every time, just with rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Is there a possibility to run simplecov coverage-tool for rails just over an rake task and not every time, when running the tests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can sort of work around this using an environment variable:

```
SimpleCov.start if ENV["COVERAGE"]
```

And then, running rake test / rspec / cucumber with

```
$ COVERAGE=true rake test
```

Comment: and in /environments/coverage.rb i just copy and paste the settings from the test.rb?

Comment: You don't need to run it in a separate Rails environment, what I meant was just a shell environment variable :)

Comment: Where do you put the `SimpleCov.start`? At the top of the rakefile?

Comment: No, in your test/spec helper as stated in the README

Comment: Was wondering this as well and reached the same conclusion. I'm not keen on specifying the environment variable every time I run rake but I didn't find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to run `SimpleCov` with rake task only is to move the setup code out of the spec helper into `Rakefile`.

```
# Rakefile

... # normal Rakefile stuff


if defined? RSpec
  task(:spec).clear

  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
    require 'simplecov'
    SimpleCov.start 'rails'
  end
end
```